# How to convert p5.js soundFile to file javascript class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I'm recording with p5.js library but i need to convert the soundFile object to a javascript file object to send it to an audio server.

how can archieve this?

my code is something like this:

```
mic = new p5.AudioIn();
mic.start();
recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
recorder.setInput(mic);
soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();

$("#record").on("click", function{
    recorder.record(soundFile);
})

$("#stop").on("click", function{
    recorder.stop();
})
$("#send").on("click", function{
    //here i need to convert soundFile object to file object 
    myuploadfile(file)
})
```

Comment: Should be in `soundFile.path`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What exactly do you mean by "javascript file object"? Can you please provide a [mcve] or a jsfiddle that we can play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The p5.sound library creates a Blob object before download it as .wav, you can see this on p5.prototype.writeFile.

The difference between a Blob and a file is just 2 extra properties: a date and a name, so, if you want to "convert" your blob to a file, just add this 2 properties:

```
function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){
    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    theBlob.name = fileName;
    return theBlob;
}
```

After that, you can manage the output as a javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [example you seek](https://p5js.org/examples/examples/Sound__Record_Save_Audio.php) to do a recording and playback. After `saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav');` you should be able to access `soundFile.path` to get the path. Of course, that will just download `mySound.wav` to your Browser.